# Equivalence of group schemes and representations of the fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I heard this result:

$\{$finite étale group schemes G/S$\}$ are equivalent to $ \{$continuous homomorphisms $\pi_1^{\text{ét}}(S,\overline{s})\to \text{Aut}(\Gamma)$ for a finite group $\Gamma\}$

I cannot prove this result, or find a reference for it. I was able to find a similar statement in Szamuely's *Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups* but it only covers the case where $S=\text{Spec}k$ for some field $k$. Also there is a similar result, but only for finite étale covers.

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a scheme $S$ with a geometric point $s$ there is an equivalence of categories
$$\{\textrm{Finite étale schemes over } S\}\to \{\textrm{Finite sets with a continuous }\pi_1(S,s)\textrm{-action} \}.$$
This should be covered in any book/notes on étale cohomology, e.g. in Milne's notes [Theorem 3.1](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf).

Now if two categories with finite products are equivalent, so will be the category of their group objects i.e. the category whose objects are $(C,m,i,e)$ objects of the original category together with multiplication map, inverse, and identity section subject to the usual group axioms.

Since group objects in the category of finite étale schemes (resp. finite sets with $\pi_1(S,s)$-action) are exactly finite étale group schemes (resp. finite groups with $\pi_1(S,s)$-action*), you get the desired equivalence.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. Certainly if two categories are equivalent so are the categories of their group objects, since you can just shuffle the structure back and forth. And definitely the group objects are what you say they are.

Comment: Exacty, if you have any more doubts, let me know and I will elaborate